# Blender freezes when adjusting editing materials and value slider

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view, properties, performance

Been having this issue for a long time and can't seem to find the answers. While in Render View any material value slider adding nodes/removing etc blender will freeze and viewport goes grey while it thinks about what you just changed then will display your result, the freeze is usually about 5-10sec depending on the scene... to wait 5-10 sec every time you touch something is insane. Once in a while I'll watch a tutorial on something and amazed at how responsive the viewport is while shading in render view.

I am on a 2019 Mac Pro, AMD Radeon Pro W6800X Duo., 96gb ram. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! so after a year trying to figure this out, late last night I discovered the issue. I have 4 monitors, 3 side by side and one above the centre monitor which I use specifically for the shader/node editor. Last night I put my web browser up there to watch a movie while I work and moved my shader editor window to my right monitor. The viewport became responsive with no freezing or delays editing materials/nodes. With a bit of experimenting this issues I was having only happen on that one particular monitor, works fine on the other 3. Curious to what would cause this? Monitor driver, Duo graphics cards with 3 connected to 1 and 1 to the other, will need to test that out but if anyone has any suggestions that would be great!